# My build agent doesn't pick-up any C# tasks since I upgraded to VS2019

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Since I removed VS2017 and installed VS2019 on my system, my build agent doesn't have the Visual Studio capabilities. So, I can't build any C# project anymore. I thing the reason why I can't build any C# project is because I missed these VS capabilties.
I miss these capabilities which I had when VS2017 was installed:

VisualStudio      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\
VisualStudio_15.0           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\
VisualStudio_IDE             C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\
VisualStudio_IDE_15.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\
VS140COMNTOOLS        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\
VSTest  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow
VSTest_15.0      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow

We are using TFS2018 update 2

I reïnstalled the build agent, but that doesn't solve the problem.
After I had manually added these missing capabilities, my build agent can pick-up the build task again, but failed with this error message:
The type 'DateTime' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly. 
Can I upgrade my build agent without upgrading Team Foundation Server? Are there other solutions to solve this problem?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You hit upon the correct solution: Add the capabilities pointing to VS2019 manually. The error you're seeing is a compilation error, which you'll have to troubleshoot yourself.

Comment: I don 't know how to solve this problem. The error message says I have to include a reference to .NET Standard. But the solution compiles without any problem in VS2019 itself.